# JUnit InitializationError

Tags: java, junit

Estoy intentando probar una deque con JUnit, pero me sale un error de inicialización. El código es este:

```
package arraycirculardeque;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestDequeAddFirst {

    private Deque<String> dq1 = new ArrayCircularDeque<String>(6);
    private Deque<String> dq2 = new ArrayCircularDeque<String>(6);

    // deque vacía
    @Test
    public void testDeque1() {
        dq1.addLast("Juan");

        dq2.addFirst("Juan");
        assertEquals(dq1, dq2);
    }

    // deque con datos
    @Test
    public void testDeque2() {
        dq1.addLast("Juan");
        dq1.addLast("Pedro");

        dq2.addFirst("Pedro");
        dq2.addFirst("Juan");
        assertEquals(dq1, dq2);
    }

    // deque sin espacio
    @Test(expected = IllegalStateException.class)
    public void testDeque3() {
        dq2.addFirst("Pedro");
        dq2.addFirst("Juan");
        dq2.addFirst("Ana");
        dq2.addFirst("Pablo");
        dq2.addFirst("Maria");
        dq2.addFirst("Jorge");
        dq2.addFirst("Analia");
    }

}
```

El error que me sale es:

```
unable to make public void arraycirculardeque.TestDequeAddFirst.testDeque1() accesible: module Tp5 does not "exports arraycirculardeque" to module junit
```

Donde arraycirculardeque es un paquete y Tp5 el proyecto.

Comment: Estas usando una version de java superior a la 11?

Comment: no, java 8 y junit 5

Comment: Según tú estás usando java 8, pero tu error es por los módulos y los módulos en Java no se introdujeron hasta java 9. ¿Estás seguro estás usando java 8? Raro....

Comment: Tp5 que tipo de modulo es? Jigsaw? Maven?

Comment: Hola Alejandro! Como menciona Jaime, el error que tienes viene de una version de Java mas reciente (Java 9 en adelante) que fue cuando se introdujo el concepto de modulos.

Mas informacion acerca de tu proyecto seria util para poderte colaborar en mas detalle. Por ejemplo, tienes un archivo `module-info.java` en tu proyecto? Eso le indica a Java que quieres definir un modulo.

Por lo que comentas, esperas estar usando java 8, entonces si tienes ese fichero, intentaria eliminarlo por que entiendo no necesitas definir modulos. Quedo mas pendiente a mas informacion. Saludos!